# First step argument of Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $P$ be a transition probability matrix of a regular Markov Chain over a finite state space S. Let $M=(m_{ij})$ be a matrix of mean return times.

a) Use first step argument to establish that

$$m_{ij}=1+\sum_{k\neq j}^{} P_{ik}m_{kj}$$.

I don't know how will I prove this?

I
mean I don't know what is the form of $M=(m_{ij})$ and I don't know how to start.

Can somebody give a hint/help?. I'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem uses terminology, which is not generally accepted. Mean return time is the mean time when the process firstly return to the same initial state. And the number of transitions $T_{ij}$ until the process hits state $j$ if it starts at state $i$ is called the first passage time from $i$ to $j$. So, $m_{ij}=\mathbb ET_{ij}$ is the expectation of the first passage time from $i$ to $j$.

"First step argument"  is simply the law of total probability for expectations where the first step possibilities solve as partition of sample space.

Let $X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ denotes the Markov chain. Let $X_0=i$ be the initial state. Define $B_k=\{X_1=k\}$, $k\in S$. Total probability law implies that
$$
\mathbb ET_{ij}=\sum_{k\in S}\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_k)\mathbb P(B_k)=\sum_{k\in S}\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_k)P_{ik}.
$$
Note that $T_{ij}=1$ on the event $B_j$, and then
$$\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_j)=1.$$
If $k\neq j$, then the chain appears at state $X_1=k$ after unit time and the mean time to hit state $j$ for this case equals to $m_{kj}$. Totally
$$\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_k)=1+m_{kj}, \quad k\neq j .$$

Return to the law of total probability:
$$
\mathbb ET_{ij}=\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_j)P_{ij}+ \sum_{k\neq j}\mathbb E(T_{ij} \mid B_k) P_{ik} = 1\cdot P_{ij}+\sum_{k\neq j}(1+m_{kj})P_{ik}=
\underbrace{\sum_{k\in S}P_{ik}}_1 +  \sum_{k\neq j}m_{kj}P_{ik}.
$$

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: If I multiply by $\Pi_i$ and sum in both sides I get this:
$$\sum_{i}^{} \Pi_i m_{ij}=\sum_{i}^{} \Pi_i+\sum_{i}^{} \sum_{i}^{} \Pi_i P_{ik} m_{kj}$$ How could I simplify  it to get $\Pi_j m_{jj}=1$ ?

Comment: You denoted by $\Pi_i$ the steady-state probabilities? It seems to me that it is very difficult to obtain  $\Pi_j m_{jj}=1$. from this equation. At least I do not know how.

Comment: hmm yes? or which is the usual notation ?

Comment: Usually small letters $\pi_i$ denote stationary probabilities.